# Why Force is considered in case of Work done by two bodies?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

Suppose there are two bodies having same mass which are being moved by the same displacement with different Forces. According to the formula:

$$W=Fd$$

The work done by the body which applied more force is greater as compared to the other according to the formula. 
   Practically we would see that the work done by both is same and say that both have done the same thing.

Why is the work done by the body which applied more force than the other is greater if the displacement is same?

Comment: Are the two bodies are identical (have the same mass? Is the force applied to each the only force or net force?

Comment: Are you assuming the bodies are pushing on each other?

Comment: "we would see that the work ... is the same" Who is "we" and on what basis are "we" saying the work is the same? How are "we" defining work?

Answer (score 1):

Did the two bodies have the same acceleration?
If not, you can "see" the different work as a different final kinetic energy.
Otherwise, if the two bodies had the same acceleration and moved the same way as a consequence of different resulting forces they must have different masses (F = ma).

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the work done by the body which applied more force than the other is greater if the displacement is same?

If the $W=\vec F \cdot \vec d$ definition doesn’t make it clear for you then consider the definition that work is a transfer of energy. If you slowly lift a 1 kg book from the floor and put it on a 1 m high table then the book gained $mgh=10\ \text J$ energy so you did $10 \ \text J$ work. If you put a 100 kg sculpture on the table then the sculpture gained $mgh=1000\ \text J$ energy.

Notice that lifting the sculpture required more force and transferred more energy. Therefore since work is a transfer of energy more work must have been done.